"Schema does not exist" in PostgreSQL
When I execute this script
CREATE TRIGGER pdate_day_month_decade
AFTER UPDATE ON main."YDate"
FOR EACH ROW
    WHEN (OLD."dayMonth" IS DISTINCT FROM NEW."dayMonth")
        EXECUTE FUNCTION pdate_day_month_decade_trigger();

I get an error

ERROR:  schema "main" does not exist
SQL state: 3F000

However INSERT and UPDATE work on this schema correctly and I checked that usage of this schema is PUBLIC.
dn command result:
\dn
      List of schemas
  Name  |       Owner
--------+-------------------
 main   | postgres
 public | pg_database_owner

Result of show search path:
"$user", public


is main name of a table?


In psql do \dn and copy the results as text into your question text. 2) Also copy and paste the result of show search_path.


Hi, and welcome to SO! Unrelated, but you don't have to use quoted identifiers in PostgreSQL - life is far easier and more legible without them! I recommend you use "snake_case", but that's a matter of taste and preference.

@Vérace, you do have to use them if you want to preserve case or use reserved words or special characters. Read Identifiers.

@AdrianKlaver - yes, I possibly should have mentioned this. However, as far as I'm concerned, obliging oneself to preserve case and/or using reserved words and/or punctuation chars as table/column/ names is just asking for trouble! It makes the SQL unportable, illegible and difficult to debug! Using the KISS principle, 63 bytes is i_think_this_is_quite_long_enough_dont_you_comma_i_certainly_do?

@Vérace. The point is you may not have a choice, you have to deal with the identifier naming you have been handed.

@AdrianKlaver - OK - last word (directed to the OP), it is vastly preferable to not use identifiers which require quotes - if you are obliged to, then you have no choice. However, in the absence of such a requirement, it's easier, and better, not to use quoted identifiers. I have found that many users of PostgreSQL appear to think that quoting identifers is required, when it's (usually) not. I was just trying to pass that on - you (correctly) pointed out that it may be required. The OP can get back to us about all of this - summary: "quotes bad, unless required!"?

@kofemann it is the name of the schema. Name of relation is "YDate".

@AdrianKlaver it is $user"", public
I tried adding main to search path before the script, but this didn`t help.

That is why I asked you  to do In psql do \dn and copy the results as text into your question text.. Please provide the information requested.

Added results, @AdrianKlaver

Hmm. What does select nspname, length(nspname) from pg_namespace where nspname ilike 'main%'; return?

nspname: "main", length: 4, @AdrianKlaver


Try reindex table pg_namespace ;. 2) Can you provide more detail on what However INSERT and UPDATE work on this schema correctly  ... means?


Reindexing namespace table suggested by @AdrianKlaver worked. After this query:
reindex table pg_namespace;

Trigger successfully created in database.

I would keep an eye this, it indicates that the index was corrupted. That could either be a hardware issue or something(one) was fooling around with that table or system tables in general.
